# Checking password complexity and validity of a token during email confirmation on Identity 3.0

Tags: asp.net, validation, email, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I have a web app, using ASP.NET Identity 3.0, in which I create the users (instead of users registering themselves). I send a confirmation email to validate their email accounts. The idea is that they come in through the URL and, since they don't have a password set yet, they will set an initial password *and* validate their email in one fell swoop (I'm trying to kill two birds with one stone as elegantly as possible).

The problem is that I shouldn't confirm the email with UserManager.ConfirmEmail() if the password they entered isn't a valid password as per the complexity policy because this will expire the token. The only way I know to check if a password complies is to actually try to set it with UserManager.AddPassword() but I shouldn't try to change it *unless* I know the email confirmation token is valid.

How can I check if a password will be compliant without setting it? Or how can I check if a token is valid without expiring it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity 3.0 does provide a password validator that you could use to check if a password is valid before taking other steps.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/addb9a45cbe02a924fd4709b6ca1fcce5d77137a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/PasswordValidator.cs) is where you can find the actual code.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/addb9a45cbe02a924fd4709b6ca1fcce5d77137a/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Test/PasswordValidatorTest.cs) is where you can find some unit tests that will give you an idea of how to use the password validator.

The general usage looks like this:

```
var validator = new PasswordValidator<User>();
var result = await validator.ValidateAsync(UserManager, null, passwordToValidate);
if (result.Failed) // Failed Validation
if (result.Succeeded) // Passed Validation
```

The 2nd parameter to `ValidateAsync` is the User instance, but that may not be applicable in your situation, so it is `null` here.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. My single step process is working nicely. I had actually looked at this before but from its inline comment I thought it was meant to check if a user's password was correct without logging him in. I've only recently started working with Identity and, even though it's amazing, I'm facing the fact that it's documentation inline or otherwise is kinda weak.

Comment: Btw, interestingly that 2nd User parameter in ValidateAsync isn't even used anywhere in that method. *shrug*

Comment: I agree with your comment on the docs around Identity... awful! I was struggling that same issue just last night trying to do a code update. Glad this helped you!